# a need to parse file names to cli

Tags: php, filesystems

i have a php script where i need to create a zip archive with an array of file names

so I do this running zip via php; using shell_exec().

i hit a bump when it comes to files which has names like

/var/www/someone's file (3)

cause my zip command looks like

```
shell_exec("zip -r -j myzip.zip /var/www/someone's file (3)");
```

now i need a way to parse the file names so it looks like

/var/www/someone\'s\ file\ (3)

any help on this is much appreciated and is there any function which can do this directly ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for [`escapeshellarg()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php).